# How can I practically determine what "should" means?

Tags: practical-islam, terminology

I hear the word *should* used a lot and its meaning can be vague.  To illustrate how many times this occurs, from the single article [Forty Hadiths for Women](http://rasoulallah.net/index.php/en/articles/article/1389), the word *should* appears in:

> woman **should** take the permission of her husband before going out; women **should** not travel without mahram; women **should** have their own entrance to the mosque; women **should** not walk in the middle of the street; women **should** perform tawaf without mingling with men; men **shouldn’t** enter freely into private places where foreign women are; women **should** have their own learning venues; women **should** not carry funeral; women **should** not take off their clothes outside their homes; woman **should** not describe another woman to her husband; women **should** not speak unnecessarily in the presence of foreign men; a woman **should** not be married against her will; a woman **should** not ask for divorce without a reason; woman **should** be grateful to her husband; woman **should** not obey her husband if ordered to do a sin; woman **should** not donate from her money unless upon husband’s consent; woman **should** help her husband and his dependants; husband **should** provide for wife and children; woman **should** not wear tight clothes; woman **should** not wear false hair like Jews; woman **should** not lie and adopt falsehood; women **should** not wear high shoes; women **should** cover her face in the presence of foreign men; women **should** not show their ornaments to foreign men; women **should** not imitate men in dress, movements, and way of speech.

If we compare, e.g.:

a. "woman *should* not obey her husband if ordered to do a sin", with
  b. "women *should* not walk in the middle of the street"

we see the level of obligation is significantly different, but there is no corresponding change in phrasing.  So I can't tell which of these things are actually important without studying the Qur'an, hadith, tafsir, and fatwa in detail, which takes time.  And I'd need to do this for every one of these claims.

**Question**: How can I practically determine what *should* means?

Specifically, I'm seeking practical steps for those times when someone tells me or I read *you should XYZ*, and I want to know (a) if it's true and accurate, and (b) gauge the level of obligation.

Answer (score 2):

Muslim jurists generally distinguish between the following:

1. wajib: Actions that are obligatory: *not doing* them is a sin.
2. mustahabb or sunnah: actions that are desirable/praiseworthy, but omitting them is not a sin.
3. mubah: actions that are indifferent, neither desirable nor reprehensible, neither commanded nor forbidden.
4. makruh: actions that are not desirable, and it is best to refrain from.
5. haram: actions that are forbidden, doing them is sinful.

There are also grey areas; so for example, one action may be 'mustahabb' (desirable) according to some interpretations and wajib ('obligatory') according to other interpretations, and so on.

You're right: *should* in English can be used for either wajib or mustahabb; and *shouldn't* could be used for either 'makruh' or 'haram'; knowing which is which requires further research.