# What is the wajib hijab for women in Islam?

Tags: hijab

I want to know about the wajib hijab for women. Is full face covering includes in wajib hijab or just forehead and chin? And what about wrist and toe?
Anyone can help me so that I can improve myself

Answer (score 2):

All women above the age of puberty (around 13 yrs of age), when they are in the sight of non-mahram men, **must** cover all parts of body except face and hands. According to another opinion, feet (below ankle) can be shown.

So that means, a woman must cover all the hair, chin, neck, arms, legs etc.

[Quran al-Noor 24:31]  http://www.myquranstudy.com/Study.aspx?24:31

> “And tell the believing women to lower their gaze (from looking at
>   forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal
>   sexual acts) and not to show off their adornment except only that
>   which is apparent (like both eyes for necessity to see the way, or
>   outer palms of hands or one eye or dress like veil, gloves, headcover,
>   apron), and to draw their veils all over Juyoobihinna (i.e. their
>   bodies, faces, necks and bosoms) and not to reveal their adornment
>   except to their husbands, or their fathers, or their husband’s
>   fathers, or their sons, or their husband’s sons, or their brothers or
>   their brother’s sons, or their sister’s sons, or their (Muslim) women
>   (i.e. their sisters in Islam), or the (female) slaves whom their right
>   hands possess, or old male servants who lack vigour, or small children
>   who have no sense of feminine sex. And let them not stamp their feet
>   so as to reveal what they hide of their adornment. And all of you beg
>   Allaah to forgive you all, O believers, that you may be successful”

[Quran al-Ahzaab 33:53] http://www.myquranstudy.com/Study.aspx?33:53

> “O you who believe! Enter not the Prophet’s houses, unless permission
>   is given to you for a meal, (and then) not (so early as) to wait for
>   its preparation. But when you are invited, enter, and when you have
>   taken your meal, disperse without sitting for a talk. Verily, such
>   (behaviour) annoys the Prophet, and he is shy of (asking) you (to go);
>   but Allaah is not shy of (telling you) the truth. And when you ask
>   (his wives) for anything you want, ask them from behind a screen, that
>   is purer for your hearts and for their hearts. And it is not (right)
>   for you that you should annoy Allaah’s Messenger, nor that you should
>   ever marry his wives after him (his death). Verily, with Allaah that
>   shall be an enormity”

---

Hadith reference:

It was narrated from Safiyyah bint Shaybah that ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) used to say: When these words were revealed – “and to draw their veils all over Juyoobihinna (i.e. their bodies, faces, necks and bosoms)” – they took their izaars (a kind of garment) and tore them from the edges and covered their faces with them.

[al-Bukhaari, 4481.]

---

May Allaah have mercy on the Muhaajir women. When Allaah revealed the words “and to draw their veils all over Juyoobihinna (i.e. their bodies, faces, necks and bosoms)”, they tore the thickest of their aprons (a kind of garment) and covered their faces with them.

[Abu Dawood (4102)]

Also see Q&A:

http://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa-22614/info

https://islamqa.info/en/13998

Comment: Can you be more specific than "should"?  See [How can I practically determine what “should” means?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37675/how-can-i-practically-determine-what-should-means)  And would it be possible to add evidence to support these claims?  See [How do I add evidence to my answer?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-do-i-add-evidence-to-my-answer)

Comment: is covering the face fard too? u said no in first then gave ref of hadith in the end which says shahabas covered

Answer (score 0):

> [Verse (24:31)](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(24:31:6)) And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their
>   vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment
>   except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion
>   of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment
>   except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers,
>   their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers'
>   sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands
>   possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or
>   children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And
>   let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their
>   adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers,
>   that you might succeed.

If Quran said, means it is mandatory [FARZ].

Your next question, what part should cover? Allah described it in detail, I don't think I need to explain it any more.

- reduce [some] of their vision (lower their gaze)
- hide private parts
- not expose their adornment  except that which [necessarily] appears thereof
- wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests
- let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment

Naqab is to hide so no one can see, but some women use stylish naqab with embroidery which is not allowed because that kills the whole purpose. That make attractive and people keep watching, must be avoided.

Comment: Would it be possible to add evidence to support each of the claims?  See [How do I add evidence to my answer?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-do-i-add-evidence-to-my-answer)

Answer (score 0):

What is the hijab of women in Islam?
It is obligatory to cover the main hair of the non-mahram and it is obligatory on the woman to cover her whole body except the face and hands from the fingers to the wrists and also the feet from the fingers to the wrists.

Ref:https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%AD%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%A8#.D8.A7.D8.AD.DA.A9.D8.A7.D9.85_.D8.AD.D8.AC.D8.A7.D8.A8_2